# I've been trying to implement and AVL Tree but I keep on getting these 2 errors C2954 and C2955 and don't know how to solve them

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

Here is my code 
I have written the error messages that occured next to the corresponding lines

```
//AVL Tree implemantation
template<class Element>
class AVLtree
{
    public:
      int height(AVLnode<Element>*)const;
    int max(int,int)const;
};
//Function to get the max
template<class Element>
int AVLtree<Element>::max(int a, int b)
{
return ((a>b)?a:b);
} //Error:'AVLtree<Element>::max' : unable to resolve function overload
//Function to calculate the height
template<class Element> //Error:error C2954: template definitions cannot nest
int AVLtree<Element>::balanceFactor(AVLnode<Element>* p)
{
return (height(p->left) - height(p->right));
}
```

Comment: Please try to isolate the problem in a minimal, compilable example, rather than posting your entire program.

Comment: @merlin2011 the thing is that these functions call each other I isolated the rest

Comment: You need to give us more information. What specific error messages are  you getting? Where are they occurring? What do you think is wrong? What have you done to try to fix the problem? We're happy to help, but if you just post code and no description it feels like you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm still not familiar with the use of templates I implemented this code for ints and it worked fine after watching a couple of YouTube videos I've learned some template basics but my project is due to tomorrow and I can't seem to solve the "unable to resolve function overload" , "template definitions cannot nest" and "use of class template requires template argument list" errors I've searched and I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What are the descriptions of errors?  What compiler / platform are you using?  What line numbers are the errors referenced to?  Where are these line numbers in your posted code?  Did you post the code associated with the errors?  Please update / edit your question with the answers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 and I'm done check out the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is that you declared `max()` to be a `const` member function but you are trying to define it as a non-`const` member function. You'll need to add `const` to in the definition:

```
template<class Element>
int AVLtree<Element>::max(int a, int b) const {
    return std::max(a, b);
}
```

I can't make much sense of the other error but it may have resulted from the preceding error. Since it uses a name not declared in the excerpt of the class posted, it may also be something different.